# how to check if a word exist in a text file

Tags: java

I am new to Java and am writing a code which checks if an ID exists in a log file or not. If the ID is present in log file then it should print that ID already exist. But if it doesnt exist then it should do some task.

I have a string p1 = 1234

and wants to check if that string exist in log file or not.

```
p1 = 1234;
Scanner scanner=new Scanner("sample.log");
While(scanner.hasNextLine()){
if(p1.equals(scanner.nextLine().trim())){
 system.out.println("ID already exist")}
else{system.out.println("ID not present ")}
```

my sample.log file has some text like:

21 oct 2019, [WARN], 2324

21 oct 2019, [WARN], 1234

21 oct 2019, [INFO], 3343 and so on.

Comment: did you try using `.contains()` instead of `.equals()`?

Comment: First off, surely you want logic to be "scanner.nextline contains p1" not "p1 equals scanner.nextline". Next, you want to read the whole file and check all the lines, not just 1, before you make your decision - use a Boolean to track whether the if is found yet. If it is then stop looping. After the loop check the boolean and decide what to do print out/do. Keep going; you've nearly cracked it.

Comment: I made the following changes:  
if((scanner.nextLine().trim()).contains(p1)){}

but it is still not working

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a 1-liner for you:

```
if (new Scanner(new File(pathToFile)).useDelimiter("\\Z").next().contains(p1)) {
     System.out.println("ID already exist");
} else {
    System.out.println("ID not present ");
}
```

The “trick” here is using `"\\Z"` (regex meaning *end of entire input*), so `next()` reads in the *whole* file.

Comment: it gives an error - can  not invoke contains(String) on the primitive type boolean

Comment: My bad, it was syntax error. your code works for me. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

"Sample.log" should be given as new File("sample.log") like mentioned in the below code

```
String p1 = "1234";
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(new File(pathToFile));
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    String aString = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(aString);
    if(aString.indexOf(p1) > 0){
        System.out.println("ID already exist");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("ID not present ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html). For example:

```
// Source file: IDCheck.java

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;


public class IDCheck{

    // This method checks if ID exists in log file
    public static boolean hasID(String logFile, String id){ 
        try{
            BufferedReader buff=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(logFile));
            String s;
            while((s=buff.readLine())!=null){ 
                if(s.trim().contains(id)){
                    return true;
                }               
            }
            buff.close();
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    return false;
    }



    //Main:
    public static void main(String[] arg){

        //Now test:
        if(IDCheck.hasID("Sample.log","1234")){
            System.out.println("ID already exists");
        }else{
            System.out.println("ID not present");
        }       
    }
}
```